# How can I synchronize multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wrote this console program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object sync = new object();
    Thread[] t = new Thread[10];
    int count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
    {
        t[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                int inc = count;
                Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", count);
                count = inc + 1;
            }
        });
    }

    foreach (var t1 in t)
    {
        t1.Start();
    }

    foreach (var t1 in t)
    {
        t1.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("\nFinal Count= {0}", count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I get this result in the output :

```
Count: 0
Count: 1
Count: 2
Count: 3
Count: 4
Count: 5
Count: 6
Count: 7

Final Count= 7
Count: 8
Count: 9
```

and when I run the app multiple time I'm getting more different results
but I want to see this result :

```
Count: 0
Count: 1
Count: 2
Count: 3
Count: 4
Count: 5
Count: 6
Count: 7
Count: 8
Count: 9

Final Count= 10
```

why does it return different results and how do I fix this?

Comment: `count = inc + 1;` makes little sense. Post actual code.

Comment: The "final count" is achievable but if you want the numbers in order then just don't use threads.

Answer (score 2):

Try do don't manually create/terminate threads like this, it's a time consuming operation and it doesn't scale well.

Use the `ThreadPool` instead.

Or better: use **tasks**, and synchronize them by using `await Task.WhenAll(list of your tasks)`

Comment: Not so fast. This is clearly "demo" code, it depends on what is to be executed in the actual threads later.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I see what you mean (and it's valid), but I still would recommend tasks instead of threads. Unless the OP provides information about why threads would be better than tasks (long running operations...etc), tasks will provide more simple ways to synchronize their execution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of this :

```
foreach (var t1 in t)
{
    t1.Join();
    Console.WriteLine("\nFinal Count= {0}", count);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You should write:

```
foreach (var t1 in t)
{
    t1.Join();

}
Console.WriteLine("\nFinal Count= {0}", count);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Otherwise you will have a racing and your code will be undeterministic.

Comment: Indeed - as the original code is written, the "Final count" is displayed as soon as any one thread is detected to have completed. In fact, I'm surprised that the "Final count" message only appears once, as I'd expect to see it once per thread...

Comment: It would be so, but he's got the Console.ReadKey() inside the loop.

Comment: Of course - the program isn't even running to completion. \*facepalm\*